# regular sequences cut away the same number of dimensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Following Krull's principal ideal theorem in AG books I have been reading I *expected* to see some result to the effect of the following:

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring with the property that $$\operatorname{ht} ({\frak q})+ \operatorname{coht} ({\frak q})= \dim (R) $$

for every prime ideal ${\frak q}\subset R$ (for example a polynomial ring over a field or any quotient or localization of such). Then if $$I= (s_1,...,s_k)\subset R$$ is an ideal, where $s_i$ is never a zerodivisor of $R/(s_1,...,s_{i-1})$ (i.e. $s_1,...,s_k$ is a *regular sequence*), then $R/I$ is of *pure* dimension $\dim(R)-k$.

The fact that such a seemingly obvious and useful corollary does not follow the discussion of Krull's principal ideal theorem makes me think I am doing something wrong. Indeed this result would seem to me to be precisely *the point* of regular sequences.

Isn't this claim true?

Answer (score 1):

By Krull's ideal theorem, for a minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ containing $I$, $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q})\leq k.$ Then $\operatorname{coht}(\mathfrak{q})=\dim R-ht(\mathfrak{q})\geq \dim R-k$.

Now $\dim R/I=\max \operatorname{coht} (\mathfrak{q})$ where maximum is over all minimal prime ideals of $R$ containing $I$. Hence $\dim R/I\geq \dim R-k$.

On the other hand, $\dim R/(s_1)\leq \dim R-1$ and by induction $\dim R/I\leq \dim R-k. $ So you have the equality $\dim R/I=\dim R-k$.

Comment: thank you for your help